# Get a seg fault hen attempting to reconfigure X after upgrade 16.04 -> 18.04

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, segmentation-fault

I finally got around to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 on my KDE desktop system, but now my second screen doesn't get recognized anymore, I've googled around but could not find what's working. Can anyone here help me?
What I've tried so far:

What I have tried:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +*default 1920/508x1080/286+0+0  default
```

(with two monitors connected, one DVI, the other one with VGA), the screen connected to the DVIport is currently working. Thus under Systemsettings - ? Monitor, Ionly see one screen (defaiult monitor) with the wrong resolution (1920 x 1080)

What I `xrandr` sees:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +*default 1920/508x1080/286+0+0  default
```

What I tried:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
$ sudo systemctl restart display-manager
```

I've been told, that there should be no need to go to the NVIDIA web page and download the drivers from there.

Right after login (once Plasma has started)  the screen flickers at about a 2Hz frequency for a few seconds until it stabilizes and shows the screen with a margin of about an inch on each side, maybe a bit less on the top & the bottom...

And when I launch the `nvidia-settings` application, the screen flickers just like after logging in and no configuration application actually appears nor does it say anything on the shell...

And I've got the following files (no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, though):

```
:/etc/X11/Xsession.d$ ls -l
total 96
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1062 Nov 15  2017 20dbus_xdg-runtime
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2030 Jan 20  2012 20x11-common_process-args
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  878 Mar 30  2010 30x11-common_xresources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  389 Mar 22  2012 35x11-common_xhost-local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  187 Jul  1  2008 40x11-common_xsessionrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1568 May 20  2011 50x11-common_determine-startup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  743 Apr 19  2018 55gnome-session_gnomerc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  664 May 16  2015 55xfce4-session
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  146 Jan 20  2012 60x11-common_localhost
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  991 Apr 19  2018 60x11-common_xdg_path
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  336 Mar 26  2014 70gconfd_path-on-session
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1541 Mar 21  2015 70im-config_launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  123 Dec  7  2015 70xdg-kubuntu-dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  752 Nov 15  2017 75dbus_dbus-launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  143 Nov 28  2012 80appmenu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  142 Nov 28  2012 80appmenu-gtk3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2430 Sep 21  2016 80im-switch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  326 Apr 12  2012 80kubuntu-xmodmap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1027 Feb 24  2012 90consolekit
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  880 Nov 30  2017 90gpg-agent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  368 Mar 12  2018 90qt-a11y
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  629 Mar 30  2010 90x11-common_ssh-agent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  513 Dec  1  2015 95dbus_update-activation-env
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  166 Jul  1  2008 99x11-common_start
```

But get:

```
ron@ronDesktopHome:/etc/X11/Xsession.d$ grep -rn Monitor *
ron@ronDesktopHome:/etc/X11/Xsession.d$
```

Ha, I also tried:

```
$sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
$sudo X -configure
```

and got:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-138-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux ronDesktopHome 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-66-generic root=UUID=b0488ebc-79a6-49dc-b86f-fd3d9b1d746a ro quiet splash nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw vt.handoff=1
Build Date: 25 October 2018  04:11:27PM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Oct 25 18:04:37 2019
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x5582267b98cd]
(EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x558226601000+0x1bc669) [0x5582267bd669]
(EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f97b448c000+0x12890) [0x7f97b449e890]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x558226601000+0xb22b4) [0x5582266b32b4]
(EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86BusProbe+0x9) [0x55822668b229]
(EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0x7f1) [0x558226699e71]
(EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x558226601000+0x56cd3) [0x558226657cd3]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f97b40bcb97]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x558226641b8a]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x50
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Aborted
```

where the log file doesn't contain much useful info either, does it?:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[ 39519.761] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[ 39519.761] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 39519.761] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-138-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[ 39519.761] Current Operating System: Linux ronDesktopHome 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64
[ 39519.761] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-66-generic root=UUID=b0488ebc-79a6-49dc-b86f-fd3d9b1d746a ro quiet splash nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw vt.handoff=1
[ 39519.761] Build Date: 25 October 2018  04:11:27PM
[ 39519.761] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[ 39519.761] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[ 39519.761]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 39519.761] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 39519.761] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Oct 25 18:05:44 2019
[ 39519.761] (II) Loader magic: 0x5574ce79b020
[ 39519.761] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 39519.761]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 39519.761]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[ 39519.761]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[ 39519.761]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 39519.762] (--) using VT number 3

[ 39519.762] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 39519.763] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 39519.765] (EE) 
[ 39519.765] (EE) Backtrace:
[ 39519.765] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x5574ce50c8cd]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5574ce354000+0x1bc669) [0x5574ce510669]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f3d8104e000+0x12890) [0x7f3d81060890]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5574ce354000+0xb22b4) [0x5574ce4062b4]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86BusProbe+0x9) [0x5574ce3de229]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0x7f1) [0x5574ce3ece71]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5574ce354000+0x56cd3) [0x5574ce3aacd3]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f3d80c7eb97]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x5574ce394b8a]
[ 39519.765] (EE) 
[ 39519.765] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x50
[ 39519.765] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 39519.765] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[ 39519.765] (EE) 
[ 39519.765] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 39519.765] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 39519.765] (EE) 
[ 39519.766] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```